# connect external GPU to laptop with micro-HDMI

Tags: laptop, hdmi, gpu

Is there any way to connect an external GPU to my laptop though the micro-HDMI (type D) port? Do GPUs in general support this? I'm mostly aiming for sub-$200 graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not work.  HDMI is not a graphics bus and you cannot connect a graphics card to it.  There are external GPUs, that use Thunderbolt and USB.